# Golang MissingFieldOrMethod (input.scanUser undefined (type api.User has no field or method scanUser)

Tags: go, undefined, telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing a training tg bot in golang. in the course of work, I decided to make the architecture similar to Handler-> Services-> Repository. The objects with which I will have to work I placed in the global directory (struct User)

```
package api

import "github.com/mymmrac/telego"

type User struct {
    Id       int
    Name     string
    Username string
}

func (user *User) scanUser(m *telego.Message) {
    user.Id = int(m.Chat.ID)
    user.Name = m.Chat.FirstName
    user.Username = m.Chat.Username
}
```

but when i try to use the scanUser in directory /pkg/telegram/ method i can't do it because of MissingFieldOrMethod error

```
package telegram

import (
    "fmt"

    api "github.com/NoviyNapoleon/GoTelegramBOT"
    "github.com/mymmrac/telego"

    tu "github.com/mymmrac/telego/telegoutil"
)

func (b *Bot) authorization() func(bot *telego.Bot, update telego.Update) {
    return func(bot *telego.Bot, update telego.Update) {
        var input api.User

        input.scanUser(update.Message)
        b.service.Authorization.CreateUser(input)

        _, _ = bot.SendMessage(tu.Message(
            tu.ID(update.Message.Chat.ID),
            fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", update.Message.From.FirstName),
        ))

    }
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: please read all of https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started which will explain how to import functions across packages.